# How to send a future email using AT command

Tags: php, email, cron, schedule, at-job

I just need to send **one** email into the future, so I figured i'd be best at using `at` rather than using `cron`.  This is what I have so far, its messy and ugly and not that great at escaping:

```
<pre>
<?php
    $out = array();

    // Where is the email going?
    $email = "you@gmail.com";

    // What is the body of the email (make sure to escape any double-quotes)
    $body = "This is what is actually emailed to me";
    $body = escapeshellcmd($body);
    $body  = str_replace('!', '\!', $body);


    // What is the subject of the email (make sure to escape any double-quotes)
    $subject = "It's alive!";
    $subject = escapeshellcmd($subject);
    $subject  = str_replace('!', '\!', $subject);


    // How long from now should this email be sent? IE: 1 minute, 32 days, 1 month 2 days.
    $when = "1 minute";

    $command= <<<END
    echo "
            echo \"$body\" > /tmp/email;
            mail -s \"$subject\" $email < /tmp/email;
            rm /tmp/email;
    " | at now + $when;
END;

    $ret = exec($command, $out);
    print_r($out);
?>

</pre>
```

The output should be something like

**warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh

job 60 at Thu Dec 30 19:39:00 2010**

However I am doing something wrong with exec and not getting the result?

The main thing is this seem very messy. **Is there any alternative better methods for doing this?**

PS: I had to add apache's user (www-data for me) to /etc/at.allow ...Which I don't like, but I can live with it.

Comment: Are you sure `exec()` is working at all? Try `print exec('echo 1');` to test you're not a safe mode victim. Else add `2>&1` to see if the shell complains due to the lengthy syntax. Also try creating a temporary shell script to read from, and use single quotes for the inner echo.

Comment: Yeah, I am getting the emails 1 minute in the future. I also have safemode turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing basically

```
mail | at
```

which would pipe mail's output to the at command. This is incorrect. The mail command will execute immediately, and the output (usually nothing, unless there was a warning) will then be scheduled to run at whatever time you specify.

Your script should dump the mail commands into a file, then do an exec() on

```
at whenver < mailcmd.sh
```

Comment: He's actually writing a complete mailcmd using the outer echo. But assembling a separate script seems a better approach anyway.

Comment: Both are rather confusing but I felt this was more readable, for me. Also, I am echoing commands to be ran at a later date, these commands will create the temp only when at the time of execution. Your idea is to store the commands to a file, load the file to at, then you want to delete the temp file.  I include the creation/deletion of the tmp file in the echo.